# How to show the plan in the top of each slide beamer theme JuanLesPins

Tags: beamer

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}



\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
```

[image]

On the place of introduction.. I want to the frame appear introduction   un peu de vocabulaire  coloration dans les graphes
and whenever I change the section the color of each one change to clarify in which section I am

[image]

This is my plan of presentation, I want this three sentences appear in the top of the frame

Comment: Which plan? Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable! Do not only throw a code at us, please explain in your words your issue, you can also add an image of your result and mark there what you want   to change ....

Answer (score 1):

If you want the navigation across the top that is usually set via the choice of theme e.g. {Dresden} However here I have changed {JuanLesPins} to include similar settings so that as requested the 3 sections are in the heading.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz} % declare the xcolor package before tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usecolortheme[rgb={0.2,0.2,1.0}]{structure}

\title[Short title]{The girl in the mirror}
\subtitle{A day in the life of}

% footline data, first remove deadly sin 1 = redundant navigator
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % or \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\author[Nom]{Meriem Divitcha} \institute[Institution]{Universty de vivre}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{Foot}{\hspace{1cm}\insertauthor\hfill\insertinstitute\hfill\insertframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[Foot] % now display modified footer


\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginSection[] {\begin{frame}{Plan de pr\'esentation} \tableofcontents[current]\end{frame} }

\begin{document}

\titlepage{\small présentatrice}\newpage % or \maketitle

% \begin{frame}\tableofcontents\end{frame} replaced by per section contents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Todays lecture is an introduction to latex
\end{frame}

\section{Un peu de vocabulaire}
\begin{frame}{Un peu de vocabulaire}
un peu de vocabulaire 
\end{frame}

\section{Coloration dans les graphes}
\begin{frame}{Coloration dans les graphes}
coloration dans les graphes
\begin{columns}[c] % Columns centered vertically.
\column{5.5cm} % Adjust column width to taste.
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\column{5.5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: no. i want theme all in the top in the same time